# iterator yielding n-tuples from an iterator as oneliner expression

Tags: python, generator, one-liner

What I'm looking for is a oneliner-variant of the function `batched(iterable, n)` described in the code section of [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that will batch data into tuples of a certain length.

Assume the source to be an iterator of arbitrary length, e.g. an iteration over sys.stdin which receives strings in my usecase.

In the end, I would like to have a generator which yields tuples of a certain length with the last tuple also potentionally being shorter (depending on the total number of items).

AFAIK, `batched(iterable, n)` will be implemented in Python 3.12 which is due to be released later this year, yet I would like to learn how a oneliner-solution could look like with the current release.

This is what I've come up with so far (for an example tuple-length of 2):

```py
from itertools import islice, zip_longest

foo=('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg',) ## for simulating sys.stdin

# a oneliner that gets close but would fill lacking elements with None, so
# list(slicepairs0) would be [('aaa', 'bbb'), ('ccc', 'ddd'), ('eee', 'fff'), ('ggg', None)]
slicepairs0 = zip_longest(*[iter(foo)]*2)

# a oneliner that gets close but ignores possibly remaining elements, so
# list(slicepairs1) would be [('aaa', 'bbb'), ('ccc', 'ddd'), ('eee', 'fff')]
slicepairs1 = zip(*[iter(foo)]*2)

# a function similar to how batched() is currently implemented
def giveslicepair(foo):
  fooi=iter(foo)
  while nextslice := tuple(islice(fooi,2)):
    yield nextslice

# this iterator does what it should but relies on the generator-funtion giveslicepair(), so
# list(slicepairs2) would be [('aaa', 'bbb'), ('ccc', 'ddd'), ('eee', 'fff'), ('ggg',)]
slicepairs2 = ( item for item in giveslicepair(foo) )
```

I tried around to embody the functionality of giveslicepair() into the iterator expression on the last line but couldn't get it working. Feels like I'm overlooking something obvious here and would be thankful for hints how to do this in a performant and pythonic way.

Sidenote: in real world application, the size of the tuples is expected to typically be something around 50 to 400 instead of only 2. The number of lines being fed may vary greatly and could be anything from 1 to billions.

#### EDIT

For the sake of completeness and based on the accepted answer, the last line I was looking for (albeit not making use of a comprehension construct which I thought would be the way to go) could be written as:

```py
# list(slicepairs3) would also be [('aaa', 'bbb'), ('ccc', 'ddd'), ('eee', 'fff'), ('ggg',)]
# but without the need for calling giveslicepair(foo)
slicepairs3 = iter(lambda it=iter(foo): tuple(islice(it, 2)), tuple())
```

Comment: Why do you want a one-liner, instead of the function definition already provided?

Comment: @chepner: main reasons for this is that a) i had the feeling that this should be quite feasible but I could not wrap my head around how to do so and b) this function is only called and used once inside a shortish wrapper that I would prefer to keep rather compact instead of inflating it with additional function definitions, at least if I would still consider it as being somewhat human-readable.

Comment: What is the point of the last comprehension? `giveslicepair(foo)` should give you the generator you're expecting.

Comment: @Tranbi: You are perfectly right, the intention of this comprehension is to illustrate that I would like to do what `giveslicepair(foo)` does but without calling that function and within the comprehension. So in other words, I look for a way how to wrap the contents of the function into the last lines comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want one liner you can use `iter()` with `lambda` argument:

```py
from itertools import islice

def one_line_batched(iterable, n):
    return iter(lambda it=iter(iterable): tuple(islice(it, n)), tuple())

print(list(one_line_batched('ABCDEFG', 3)))
```

Prints:

```
[('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('G',)]
```

Comment: just learned that `iter()` has a [variant with a sentinel](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) resembling the iteration stop criteria, nice!